# No sound after install of 20.04.3 LTS on Linx 1010B

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I am new to Linux and I’m having trouble getting sound to work on my Linx 1010B 2 in 1 Tablet with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Sound works fine from the live USB, but not once installed. It appears to be a problem with the way ALSA is sees the soundcard:

- Live USB:

  ```
  [bytcrrt5640    ]: bytcr-rt5640 - bytcr-rt5640
                        bytcr-rt5640
  ```
- Install:

  ```
  [rt5640         ]: SOF - sof-bytcht rt5640
                        sof-bytcht rt5640
  ```

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

In my case (MPMAN Converter9), an upgrade to the latest lts (22.04) fixed the problem.